# Setting up variables in package.json

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I would like to set env variables in package.json. I have reached a point, but I can't achieve what I would like ideally is:

```
    {
       "scripts": {
         "start": "ng serve --port $my_port",
         "electron:serve": "wait-on tcp:$my_port && npx electron . --reload",
         "start:desktop": "npm-run-all -p electron:serve start"
       }
   }
```

So if I run for instance:

```
npm run start:desktop --port=4201
```

I could get the result I want starting the services on 4201 port and waiting that port before starting electron.

What I have managed is the following:

```
{
       "scripts": {
         "start": "cross-env-shell ng serve --port $npm_config_port",
         "electron:serve": "cross-env-shell wait-on tcp:$my_port && npx electron . --reload",
         "start:desktop": "npm-run-all -p electron:serve start"
       }
}
```

Which works quite fine, however in case I don't have any port i.e.

```
npm run start:desktop
```

I would like to have a default port.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You were so close to the answer according to

> [Kevin Kreuzer May 22, 2019](https://kevinkreuzer.medium.com/flexible-npm-scripts-89b5ec0c5b46)

You can set your script for example

```
"start": "http-server -p $PORT"
```

The `PORT` variable is now controlled by the caller of the script.
So you can set the desired `PORT` and pass it to your script as followed:

```
PORT=3000 npm run start
```

And setting default variable would as followed:

```
"server:start": "http-server -p ${PORT:-8080}"
```

Finally if you're using custom script file you can access the port as followed:

```
if (process.argv.indexOf('-p') && process.argv[process.argv.indexOf('-p') + 1]) {
  console.log('port', process.argv[process.argv.indexOf('-p') + 1]);
}
```

Comment: I'm using git-bash on windows, so it doesn't work this

Comment: I think this is related to npm not OS

Comment: in Windows you need to use %PORT% instead of $PORT and you need to have https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env. so if I use 

"server:start": "cross-env-shell http-server -p ${PORT}"

It's going to work fine, but not the default value i.e. 

"server:start": "cross-env-shell http-server -p ${PORT:8333}"

Comment: Great, It's a good thing to always know the OS you're working on, but this question was tagged as nodejs and npm, not shell

Comment: the package.json should be OS independent, but it seems it is not :/